# On key up / change / blur using latest tinyMCE version 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I get some live validator results via ajax and I would like to integrate this to work with the latest version of tinyMCE. What I need is to call my validator function on change, keyup and blur of the tinyMCE editor. I have looked at the documentation and came across `onKeyUp` event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        tinyMCE.init({
            selector:'textarea',
            menubar:false,
            plugins: 'link image code advlist',
            setup : function(ed) {
              ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) {
                  console.debug('Key up event: ' + e.keyCode);
              });
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I try to use this (same code as documentation) I am getting the error:

```
 SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'add' of undefined or null reference
```

I am wondering whether this is deprecated as of version 4.0 but I cannot find anything in the 4x documentation for onkeyup/change/blur events.

Comment: neighter can i verify this. tinymce4 is still beta and not well documented

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
tinymce.init({
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('keyup', function (e) {  
            //your custom logic  
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Tinymce 4 changed the event handling syntax:

tinymce 3:
editor.onInit(editor, args) { // Custom logic });

tinymce 4:
editor.on('init', function(args) { // Custom logic });